# Deploying WAR file in Amazon AWS - Tomcat and Apache HTTP Server conflict

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-ec2, tomcat6

I'm using an Amazon Linux AMI instance and I've deployed a war file on it.

[image: The Console]

The deployed war file shows up in the 'webapps' folder of tomcat6.

The real problem is - Apache HTTP 2.2 server is also installed.

When I access my instance's URL (http://ec2-107-20-92-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com), I see the default page of Apache HTTP 2.2 Only, which, if I'm not wrong, works on port number 80.

Now, how do I get my Apache HTTP 2.2 Server communicate with tomcat6 to display the website deployed in Tomcat?

Or, are there any other alternatives to it?

(I use MacOS X's terminal to connect to my Instance and I uploaded the WAR on S3 to deploy it in tomcat.)

TIA :)

Comment: Is it important for you to access your webapp via Apache? Otherwise, just shut down the apache service and reconfigure tomcat to work on port 80 instead of 8080

Comment: Otherwise, check [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html) out for details

Answer (score 0):

In addition to mac's suggestions (shutting down Apache and making Tomcat listen at port 80, or configuring the Tomcat connector on Apache), you might also set a pair of `ProxyPass`/`ProxyPassReverse` directives on your Apache configuration, like the example at [mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).

If you decide to follow this suggestion, your rules would look like follows (in the `VirtualHost` listening at port 80):

```
ProxyPass / http://ec2-107-20-92-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://ec2-107-20-92-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked. 
I deleted the instance and tried the same with Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit instance, it worked.
I have no clue why it didnt work in Amazon Linux AMI :(